# How many world seeds are in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering about how many seeds are in Minecraft(1.8.7) and how it ocuppies so few disk space? I think that there are a lot of seeds per world type, calculating this also for EVERY customized combinations. I am sure that they are over zillions. **Can you tell me the number of seeds?**

Comment: I am just asking about the number of seeds. For example,if someone plays every world type with every seed and every customized possibility(example:sliders moved by 1 to another direction,I'm sure that someone won't really do that). On how many seeds that person would have played? @Ionic

Comment: @5pike the characters you input are actually irrelevant. The entire text is hashed into a single value.

Comment: Minecraft doesn't store every possible world. Worlds are generated randomly, and the seed is used to influence the random number generator (in a predictable way, so that if you use the same seed it makes the same "random" numbers)

Comment: The misunderstanding you seem to have is that seeds are something like level passwords in some old-school games - they are not. Instead, each seed simply represents a starting point to generate the whole world, piece-by-piece as needed. So there's no "special", "hidden" seeds - the main point of using a custom seed (apart from entertainment value) is so that you can play on the same map as your friends - you both agree to play in a world with a seed of say `HumblePhoenix`, and both of you will have the same starting terrain, resources etc.

Comment: You may want to learn about [pseudo random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_random_number_generator).

Comment: I knew what is a seed. I restarted many worlds using that. @Luaan

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 (2<sup>64</sup>) possible seeds. All seeds are a number, if letters are entered into the seed box, Java's `hashCode()` function is used to turn it into a number.

Seeds do not use up much disk space (stored as a long integer, meaning just 8 bytes per world) because only a seed that has been chosen for a world is stored; not all 18 quintillion. When a seed is needed for world generation, a random one is generated from the system clock (or entered manually by the user) and is then stored and used to generate the world.

How many possible worlds can generate, **including customization options**? Probably more than any computer can calculate given [all of the float sliders available in a customized world.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPjD3.png)

---

Here's an image showing a randomly generated seed:

[image]

-3,010,441,696,458,036,422 is far lower than both -2,147,483,648 and -140,737,488,355,328. This means that seeds use higher than 32 bit and 48 bit signed integer ranges.

Comment: Your edit doesn't add anything useful to your answer. Please revert it and add it as a comment on the answer you believe to be incorrect.

Comment: @Lilienthal The edit shows that the range of seeds is (at least) 2^64, enforcing my answer. I think it is very useful to know when an answer is correct.

Comment: @ratchetfreak The seed shown in the image was randomly generated, and is outside the range of a 48 bit number.

Comment: @colorfusion then they must have changed RNG since I last checked

Comment: Do you have any idea how many world possibilities there actually are? Does the procedural generation actually have an entropy of 64 bits, or is it closer to say 32 bits?

Comment: @colorfusion The image might well be useful (even if a single value doesn't say much about the range), but answers should generally be self-contained. It also comes across as rather passive agressive to single out other answers for being incorrect, especially if you don't offer the other poster a chance to improve or retract his answer by leaving a comment.

Comment: @Lilienthal The other answer was the accepted answer at the time of that edit, so I felt the need to notify OP that the answer they accepted is wrong, and why it is wrong. I'm not trying to be passive aggressive, just make sure people have the right information. If my answer is incorrect, then I'd be happy for someone to write another answer with the correct answer, mentioning why mine is incorrect.

Comment: You say that the number you are showing is "far lower than the -2,147,483,648 that Kevin van der Velden claims is the minimum value" but you also say "Java's hashCode() function is used to turn it into a number." meaning it's just another way to say `-140449792`, which is not less than `-2147483648`. Which is true?

Comment: @JonHanna I believe `hashCode()` is only used if the seed entered has letters in it. If you enter "1" into the seedbox, the level seed is just 1. -140449792 does not create the same world as  -3010441696458036422.

Comment: @JonHanna `hashCode()` is only used if the entered seed has letters in it. It wouldn't be used on -3010441696458036422.

Answer (score 20):

I originally stated that Minecraft uses Java's default `Random` class for pseudo-random number generation.  [`Random` uses 48-bit seeds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

However, that would imply that the seeds 1 and 2<sup>48</sup>+1 result in the same world, which others have pointed out is not true.  So I did some more digging.

---

Minecraft appears to use `Random` everywhere *except* for the biome-generation code.  There, it uses its own homespun random generator.  From GenLayer.java:

```
protected int nextInt(int upperBound)
{
    int randVal = (int)((this.chunkSeed >> 24) % (long)upperBound);

    if (randVal < 0)
    {
        randVal += upperBound;
    }

    this.chunkSeed *= this.chunkSeed * 6364136223846793005L + 1442695040888963407L;
    this.chunkSeed += this.worldGenSeed;
    return randVal;
}
```

This is a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with values `a = 6364136223846793005` and `m = 1442695040888963407`.  This will indeed produce 2<sup>64</sup> distinct output streams, and thus **there are 2<sup>64</sup> distinct worlds.**

The claim on the Minecraft wiki that *"Multiplayer seeds may only have 2<sup>48</sup> possible values [..] due to using `Random.nextLong()`"* is incorrect.  The single-player and multiplayer world generators are not different.

---

The use of `Random` everywhere else *does* mean that some things will be the same between seeds that are off by 2<sup>48</sup>, such as seeds 1 and 2<sup>48</sup>+1.  For example, the location of ores should be almost the same between the two *(except for ores removed by cave-systems)*.

Also, the use of per-chunk seeds has some interesting consequences.  For example, given the small number of biomes and the large number of chunks, in any given world there is a very high probability that there are two chunks which are exactly the same.  Finding those chunks, however, involves math which is beyond me.  If anyone is interested in figuring it out, the code for initializing the `chunkSeed` is

```
public void initChunkSeed(long chunkX, long chunkY)
{
    this.chunkSeed = this.worldGenSeed;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        this.chunkSeed *= this.chunkSeed * 6364136223846793005L + 1442695040888963407L;
        this.chunkSeed += chunkX;
        this.chunkSeed *= this.chunkSeed * 6364136223846793005L + 1442695040888963407L;
        this.chunkSeed += chunkY;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Texenox: No.  The input value must be hashed if it's non-numeric _(since the seed must be a number)_, but if numeric inputs were also hashed, you wouldn't be able to recreate random-seed worlds, since hashes are one-way.  So the entire hashing discussion is a red-herring.

Comment: My accepted answer (and the original question) only concern possible seeds, not possible worlds; both of our answers may be correct. If your answer is the case, shouldn't worlds generated with seeds such as 281474976710657 and 1 be the same? I may be mistaken on this.

Comment: The other bits of the 64-bit seed may be used to initialize a per-chunk RNG or some other parameter, though. Minecraft uses a coordinate-based procedural terrain generation algorithm (so the world generated is independent of which way you travel first), rather than a single algorithm that runs once based on a single Random sequence.

Comment: except that `Random.nextLong()` uses two iterations of that 48 bit seed. It basically goes `Random.nextInt()` twice and pushes them together into a 64 bit number. So it is entirely possible to have a 64 bit seed come out of a `Random` object.

Comment: @corsiKa: You are confusing 64-bit output with 64-bit seed.  The PRNG will generate many billions of bits before repeating itself, so in a sense, the output is "billions of bits", much more than 64.  But the input (seed) is still 48-bits; those 48-bits completely determine what output will be.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft So, if I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, should seeds with the same 48 trailing bits produce identical worlds? And thus, seeds such as 281474976710657 and 1 should produce the exact same worlds?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'm not confusing anything with anything. Just because there are only 2^48 ways to start a Random object does not mean there are only 2^48 ways to use a random object. Chances are very likely the Random object is not created for the sole purpose of determining the seed, and even if it was it still be a stretch to infer what you've said from that statement. Your evidence simply doesn't hold.

Comment: @colorfusion: You were correct; see edit.

Comment: Just to be sure, in which version did Minecraft implement their own random for biome generation? In beta it was still using only the Java random, so only 48 bits and I'd like to know in which version they switched to their own.

Answer (score 6):

So the answer is found here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation)

Which even though it's already linked on this page no one seems to have read it all.

To summarize:

If you use a **word or phrase** then `String.hashCode()` is called and it limits your maximum amount of seeds to 2^32 because of it's implementation.

If you enter **your own number** or **let the system** determine the seed then your seed limit is 2^64 seeds.

HOWEVER:

If it's a **multiplayer world** they implement the `nextLong()` java function and the limitations of that are 2^48 possible seed options.

Comment: The last sentence makes no sense.  You are conflating multiple issues _(the seed to `new Random(seed)` is only 48-bits, which has nothing to do with "overloading `nextLong()`)_

Comment: It's `String#hashCode()` not `Java.hashCode()`. There is no `Java` class with a static method `hashCode`. (Yeah, you could get away with replace the pound with a dot, but I like to be pedantic)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'm not conflating anything I'm merely repeating what the **DEVELOPER** says on their own wiki page. And I never said anything about "overloading" `nextLong()`. So argue as much as you want, it doesn't change what the developer says they do. As for the `Java.hashCode` thing I just typed that up wrong when I was trying to summarize instead of just copy paste. The developer does list it as `String.hashCode()`. My mistake.

Comment: The developer does not maintain that wiki page, random users do.  It is not an official source of information any more than this page is.

Answer (score 2):

Seeds are hashed into a 32 bit signed integer. Which is programmer speak for a number that can be positive or negative, and is 32 values in base 2.

This gives the numbers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Depending on the implementation of Minecraft some of those might result in the same world in certain aspects like having 2 seeds with different biomes but the same heightmap.

(Partial) correction:
If you don't set a text seed minecraft will instead take the current time as it's value, which is a 64 bit number so there are more options there.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation)

Comment: If Minecraft replaces a string seed with current time, how come I always get the same world for seed "SEED"?

Comment: Is there a specific logic that prohibits entry of numbers longet than 32 bits? You are saying that the game can handle 64 bits of time values, but one can only enter 32-bit numbers manually, right?

Comment: @OrcJMR it doesn't replace the string seed with current time, if you *don't* set it then it'll use the current time. That's also why you can't insert a 64 bit value via the text field. It'll convert that text (via one way hash) to a 32 bit number. If you want to specify an arbitrary number you can edit the map file and delete the generated chunks and then start the game I suppose.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden if the string entered is numeric it gets parsed into a long and used as the seed, if it isn't then String.hashCode gets used.

Comment: Oh, my bad, reading fail on that time issue. But I've already got to the game and tested: http://i.imgur.com/x0fMiR3.png It is definitely possible to enter 64-bit integers, like those OVER 9 BILLION.

Comment: Ooh fancy, didn't know that. That's what @ratchetfreak said

Answer (score 1):

The number of seeds isn't limited by the application itself. Just by the length of the allowed value for the seed itself.

The seeds won't be stored into Minecraft. The seed itself will just be some kind of "startvalue" where the world generation starts it generate process. There isn't a seed for every world inside the game itself. You'll only get the same world as the generation process would run and generate the same world due to the same start conditions.

You can compare it by counting the steps from your way home to your work. If the same condition applies every day the same way will be used. If it snows one day or if you stay up a bit later on the day the start condition is different and your going to take another way or another time to your work. But if the same different condition would apply on another day it will end the same way. Just as an example to clarify it for the non-techies. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Computers do not truly generate random numbers. When fetching a random number, it just gives you the next number in a sequence of seemingly random numbers (they have no pattern or connection to each other).

A seed is what truly randomizes this list of numbers, in most cases, the current system time will be used as a seed. 
You could think of a seed as a way to get the same random result repeatedly.
The way a Minecraft world is generated is by an algorithm that repeatedly fetches random numbers such as when to increase surface height, etc...

Using seeds, these random numbers will be the same each time, which results in a world being the same when the same seed is used.
That being said, seeds do not take up disk space because they are simply a way to scramble/randomize the list of seemingly random numbers.

Comment: Well, It actually picks one of the seeds based on the time your computer is set at.

Comment: More importantly, this did not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score -1):

1.2413916e+61

apparently this
it is a very big number but 48x! would be the answer

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you explained where those numbers are coming from - what is 48! supposed to represent? As of right now it looks like this is completely wrong.