# Are all Minecraft maps the same?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've played this game for a while now but I have never tried using pre-made maps before. I wonder if all Minecraft maps are the same or are there a great variety of maps for me to choose from?

Answer (score 1):

If by maps you mean *worlds*, there is a **massive** amount for you to choose from, because each world uses a *seed* that is used to generate the world, and there are [2<sup>64</sup> possible seeds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227892/163757) to choose from.  For each of these seeds, the world is different.

That being said, if you use the same seed to generate two worlds, they should be identical (so long as you generate these worlds using the same version of the game).

Answer (score -1):

No I believe not. There are many different seeds that lead to different biomes and terrain which is basically a whole new map.

Comment: What information does this add that's not already covered by Timmy Jim's answer?